# How can we use 'yield return' to return IAsyncEnumerable from MediatR Request handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, yield-return, mediatr

I have a query class that implements Mediatr.IRequest like below:

```
public class ExportDataQuery : IRequest<IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>> {}
```

The query handler has been implemented as follows:

```
public class ExportDataQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<ExportDataQuery, IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>
{
  public async IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> Handle(ExportDataQuery query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
     for (int page = 1; page <= pageCount; ++page)
     {
        // Get paginated data asynchronously.
        var data = await _dbUtils.GetDataAsync(page, pageSize);
        yield return data;
     }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the following build error on compiling the above code:

```
Error CS0738 'ExportDataQueryHandler' does not implement interface member 'IRequestHandler<ExportDataQuery, IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>.Handle(ExportDataQuery, CancellationToken)'. 'ExportDataQueryHandler.Handle(ExportDataQuery, CancellationToken)' cannot implement 'IRequestHandler<ExportDataQuery, IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>.Handle(ExportDataQuery, CancellationToken)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Task<IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>'.
```

When I change return type of Handle to `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>`, I get the following error:

```
Error CS1624 The body of 'ExportDataQueryHandler.Handle(ExportDataQuery, CancellationToken)' cannot be an iterator block because 'Task<IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>' is not an iterator interface type.
```

Is there any way to use `yield return` in above request handler to return each page data one at a time?

Comment: You method marked as `async`, but there is no `await`. How is `GetData` implemented?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I added await in GetDataAsync(). Basically this method retrieve paginated data from MongoDB collection and convert it to byte array asynchronously and returns it to the caller.

Comment: Handle has to return type `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>` to implement the IRequestHandler interface. Could you create a private method, which returns `IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>`, and in this method use yield return? Then call this method from Handle?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do this; Modify your call to return the collection AsAsyncEnumerable and then use the synchronous request type by inheriting from `RequestHandler<T>` so it doesn't wrap the result in `Task<T>`

```
public class ExportDataQueryHandler : RequestHandler<ExportDataQuery, IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]>>
{
    protected override IAsyncEnumerable<byte[]> Handle(ExportDataQuery query)
    {            
        return _dbUtils.GetDataAsync(page, pageSize).AsAsyncEnumerable();           
    }
}
```